# c# best way to grab a xsd from a referenced project

Tags: c#, xsd, assemblies

My application references another a project which has an XSD file in it.

Whats the best way to get that XSD?

I did a bit of googling and found suggestions like load the assembly and get it from that, is there no easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the XSD is an embedded resource in the assembly, then you need to get it from the assembly.

If your project references and uses the assembly, then you won't need to load it again (you don't need 2 copies in memory).

The easiest way to get to the assembly, would be from one of the types defined in it:

```
Type t = typeof(TypeInOtherAssembly);
Assembly assembly = t.Assembly;
assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(...);
```

Comment: Using this to unit-test and validate XML that my project produces. Took me many attempts of googling different terms to find this tip! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you've added the XSD as a resource then the easiest way is to make the auto-generated `Properties.Resources` class publicly visible and reference the auto-generated property. You could also keep `Properties.Resources` internal and add an [`InternalsVisibleTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute to allow your other assembly to have access.

Other than that approach, you can use the [`GetManifestResourceStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream.aspx) on the target assembly to extract the XSD information.